# Show the second depth term name and image along with its associated nodes title

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a *Category* vocabulary.

- Electronics:

  - Notebooks

    - Asus

      - Node 1
    - Apple

      - Node 2
      - Node 3

I want to make a view to show popular categories, the second child term, the image field, along with 4 of its nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok based on what Joe said on previous answer I suggest a little modification to make it work:

> 1. Create a Taxonomy term based view
> 2. Add your preferred fields including "Radioactivity field" for sorting
> 3. Add Radioactivity Sort Criteria
> 4. Add a Relationship: Taxonomy term: Content with term
> 5. Add a Contextual filter: Content: "Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier" with the relationship of node (previously created
>      relationship)

Based on your comment, you can use Aggregation as Joe mentioned before to lower the chance of duplication, but since you want just a specific number of items per category you might need to use a 3rd party module such as [views_limit_grouping](https://drupal.org/project/views_limit_grouping)

> This is a basic Views style plugin that allows for a limit on the
>   number of rows displayed within a grouping field.

ok, download and install the module the usual way and head back to your views.
Remember that using this module you can group fields under another field. so you need a basic wrapper field (which is excluded from display)

> 1. Under Format Section Choose "Grouping Field (With Limit)"
> 2. Under Setting, Use your Radioactivity Field as the Grouping field Nr.1
> 3. There's a new setting after you enabled first grouping to LIMIT ITEMS TO BE DISPLAYED, so Set your preferred number and go on with the
>      rest of Grouping field that you need.

Note that for having this module to work as it supposed to you have to set views default pager to "Display All Items".

Here is the output of my views on a project similar to this one you try to achieve:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'popular_categories';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Popular Categories';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Popular Categories';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'grouping_limit';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['grouping'] = array(
  0 => array(
    'field' => 'field_term_popularity',
    'rendered' => 1,
    'rendered_strip' => 0,
    'grouping-limit' => array(
      'grouping-limit' => '4',
      'grouping-offset' => '0',
    ),
  ),
  1 => array(
    'field' => 'field_term_image',
    'rendered' => 1,
    'rendered_strip' => 0,
    'grouping-limit' => array(
      'grouping-limit' => '1',
      'grouping-offset' => '0',
    ),
  ),
  2 => array(
    'field' => 'name',
    'rendered' => 1,
    'rendered_strip' => 0,
    'grouping-limit' => array(
      'grouping-limit' => '4',
      'grouping-offset' => '0',
    ),
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Taxonomy term: Content with term */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_index';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Term ID */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['tid']['id'] = 'tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['tid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['tid']['field'] = 'tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['tid']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['tid']['separator'] = '';
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Image */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_image']['id'] = 'field_term_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_image']['table'] = 'field_data_field_term_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_image']['field'] = 'field_term_image';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_image']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_image']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_image']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_image']['click_sort_column'] = 'fid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_image']['settings'] = array(
  'image_style' => '',
  'image_link' => 'content',
  'field_formatter_class' => '',
);
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_taxonomy'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Taxonomy term: popularity */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_popularity']['id'] = 'field_term_popularity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_popularity']['table'] = 'field_data_field_term_popularity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_popularity']['field'] = 'field_term_popularity';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_popularity']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_popularity']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_popularity']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_popularity']['click_sort_column'] = 'radioactivity_energy';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_term_popularity']['settings'] = array(
  'energy' => '10',
  'type' => 'none',
  'accuracy' => '100',
  'field_formatter_class' => '',
);
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Global: Random */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['random']['id'] = 'random';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['random']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['random']['field'] = 'random';
/* Sort criterion: Taxonomy term: popularity (field_term_popularity:radioactivity_energy) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_term_popularity_radioactivity_energy']['id'] = 'field_term_popularity_radioactivity_energy';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_term_popularity_radioactivity_energy']['table'] = 'field_data_field_term_popularity';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_term_popularity_radioactivity_energy']['field'] = 'field_term_popularity_radioactivity_energy';
/* Contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['id'] = 'term_node_tid_depth_modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['field'] = 'term_node_tid_depth_modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['summary_options']['grouping'] = array(
  0 => array(
    'field' => 'field_term_popularity',
    'rendered' => 1,
    'rendered_strip' => 0,
    'grouping-limit' => array(
      'grouping-limit' => '4',
      'grouping-offset' => '0',
    ),
  ),
  1 => array(
    'field' => 'field_term_image',
    'rendered' => 1,
    'rendered_strip' => 0,
    'grouping-limit' => array(
      'grouping-limit' => '1',
      'grouping-offset' => '0',
    ),
  ),
  2 => array(
    'field' => 'name',
    'rendered' => 1,
    'rendered_strip' => 0,
    'grouping-limit' => array(
      'grouping-limit' => '4',
      'grouping-offset' => '0',
    ),
  ),
);
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'tags' => 'tags',
);
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomy term: image (field_term_image:fid) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_term_image_fid']['id'] = 'field_term_image_fid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_term_image_fid']['table'] = 'field_data_field_term_image';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_term_image_fid']['field'] = 'field_term_image_fid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_term_image_fid']['operator'] = '!=';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['field_term_image_fid']['value']['value'] = '0';

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['block_description'] = 'Popular Categories';
$translatables['popular_categories'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Popular Categories'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('node'),
  t('Term ID'),
  t('.'),
  t('All'),
  t('Block'),
);
```

Let me know if you still have any other issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a taxonomy that looks like this:
Vocab: Electronics
Terms:

- Notebooks
- Asus
- Apple
- Television
- Panasonic
- Sony

Then set up a view of Taxonomy Terms, using Filter Criteria to limit to your Electronics vocabulary (all straight forward so far).  What will help you is adding Advanced > Relationship > *Taxonomy term: Content with term* .  This will allow you to output the node fields that reference each term, per result.

Then enable Advanced > other > aggregation. This will allow you to group your results together by term.

To get closer to your required output, you can GROUP the fields using the FORMAT > settings.  Let me know if this takes you in the right direction, or even gets you close.  Or if you've tried this all before and I can remove the answer.

NOTE: the node will reference a specific TERM.  You can get access to that term's parent(s) tree etc, but bare in mind the relationships begin with the node->referenced TERM.